# Not sure on how to go about adding a share high score feature

Tags: android

I am working on a game app. I would like the players to share their high scores. So far I have created the share button and I have created a rect to match the coordinates of each share button. What I don't know  is, how to share the users high score. 
Here is the class

```
public class ScoreState extends State {
    private String easyHighScore, hardHighScore, superHardHighScore, superDuperHardHighScore;
    private int easyY,hardY,superHardY,superDuperHardY;
    private int highScoreX, shareButtonX,shareWidth,shareHeight;

    private Rect easyRect,hardRect,superHardRect,superDuperHardRect;


    @Override
    public void init() {
        highScoreX = 112;
        shareButtonX = 0;
        easyHighScore = GameMainActivity.getEasyHighScore() + "";
        hardHighScore = GameMainActivity.getHardHighScore() + "";
        superHardHighScore = GameMainActivity.getSuperHardHighScore() + "";
        superDuperHardHighScore = GameMainActivity.getSuperDuperHardHighScore() + "";

        easyY=120;
        hardY=170;
        superHardY=220;
        superDuperHardY=270;

        shareWidth = 112;
        shareHeight = 50;

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Painter g) {
        drawBackground(g);
        drawHighScoreMessage(g);
        drawHighScores(g);
        drawExitMessage(g);
        drawShareButtons(g);

    }

    private void drawHighScoreMessage(Painter g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, 70);
        g.drawString("High Scores", 10, 60);
    }

    private void drawBackground(Painter g) {
        g.setColor(Color.rgb(53, 156, 253));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH,
                GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void drawExitMessage(Painter g) {
        g.setFont(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, 50);
        g.drawString("Touch the screen to Exit.", 120, 380);
    }

    private void drawHighScores(Painter g) {
        g.setFont(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, 50);
        /*
        * 45 is added to the y coordinates of the highScoreStrings in order to
        * keep it centered with there respective share buttons. Apparently the Canvas.drawText method
        * which is the base method of g.drawString, starts drawing from the bottom instead of the top.
        * I didnt read anything to figure this out, but this is obviously the case for whatever reason.
        */
        g.drawString("Easy: " + easyHighScore, highScoreX, easyY + 45);
        g.drawString("Hard: " + hardHighScore, highScoreX, hardY + 45);
        g.drawString("SuperHard: " + superHardHighScore, highScoreX, superHardY + 45);
        g.drawString("SuperDuperHard: " + superDuperHardHighScore, highScoreX, superDuperHardY + 45);
    }
    private void drawShareButtons(Painter g){

        g.drawImage(Assets.share, shareButtonX, easyY);
        easyRect = new Rect( shareButtonX,  easyY,  shareButtonX + shareWidth,  easyY + shareHeight);

        g.drawImage(Assets.share, shareButtonX, hardY);
        hardRect = new Rect( shareButtonX,  hardY, shareButtonX + shareWidth,  hardY + shareHeight);

        g.drawImage(Assets.share, shareButtonX, superHardY);
        superHardRect = new Rect( shareButtonX,  superHardY,  shareButtonX + shareWidth,  superHardY + shareHeight);

        g.drawImage(Assets.share, shareButtonX, superDuperHardY);
        superDuperHardRect = new Rect( shareButtonX, superDuperHardY , shareButtonX + shareWidth,  superDuperHardY + shareHeight);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
        Rect usersTouchRect = new Rect(scaledX,scaledY,scaledX,scaledY);

         //This is where I would like the sharing to take place
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            if (easyRect.intersect(usersTouchRect)){

            }else if(hardRect.intersect(usersTouchRect)){

            }else if (superHardRect.intersect(usersTouchRect)){

            }else if (superDuperHardRect.intersect(usersTouchRect)){

            }
            else{
            setCurrentState(new MenuState());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

As you can see, the only missing step here is knowing how to share high scores when the share button is pressed.

Comment: you can generate an image showing score and user image and some text and share it

Comment: @jagapathi The issue i'm having is the actual functionality of sharing via facebook,twitter. he user is able to see his own scare.

Comment: Your question says nothing about Facebook or Twitter... Why aren't you using the Google Play Games API, though?

Comment: @cricket_007 it doesn't say Facebook or Twitter specifically, but it's obvious I was referring to any form of communicatable media. I don't know how to use the Google Play Games API. This is an App i was developing about 1.5 years ago and i'm just getting back to it. I was going from a book I read. My knowledge isn't very robust.

Comment: Well, if you want to share to those sites, you'll need access to their Android SDKs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the score on the social platforms like facebook or twitter, you need to integrate the platform specific sdk.
For facebook see

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Other form of this can be that you use Google Play Game Services and create a leaderboard. All the members and their score will be listed on that leaderboard.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards